# Using residue theorem to solve this integral

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{1-hz-h\sqrt{z^2-1}\cos x}$$
For $z$ a complex number.

I couldn't find a contour to evaluate this integral. Please could you give me some options for the contour.

I think I have to use the contour $|z|=1$, but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: All the other constants are just extra noise (assuming they are constant w.r.t. $x$), so rewrite it as$$I=\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{a-b\cos x}$$By symmetry,$$2I=\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{dx}{a-b\cos x}$$now use $s=e^{ix}$.

Comment: I tried $dx=\frac{ds}{is}$ and $\cos x=\frac{s+s^{-1}}{2}$ then I get $$I=-\frac{2}{i}\oint_{|s|=1} \frac{1}{bs^2-2as+b}\frac{ds}{si}$$. Is this right?

Comment: I'm not too certain where you're getting the constants out from from. Aside from that it looks correct.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. When I solve for the poles of $\frac{1}{bs^2-2as+b}$ I got two poles of first order, but my question is: Which of the two poles must be within the region enclosed by the contour, in order to use the residue thoerem?

Comment: Depends on $h,z$ I think. In any case, its a little past my bedtime. If no-one has helped you by the morrow, I suppose I'll be back.

Comment: Okay. No problem, I hope someone helps me today or tomorrow, there is no hurry

Comment: Isn't $$I=-\frac{2}{i}\oint_{|s|=1} \frac{1}{bs^2-2as+b}ds$$

Comment: OH.It is @MyGlasses